# Animated series about a football team participating in a fictional league with other teams who always cheat

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

About an year ago (I think sometime in October[?]) I was stuck watching an animated series about a fictional football team where they participated in a (again, fictional) football league where all the teams were strong but cheated to increase their chances of winning against the main team.

- It had no signs of any futuristic or otherwise technologically advanced stuff, except some things, like an antigravity chamber and a bunch of other stuff I cannot remember.
- I remember it to be a (possible) reboot of an older animated series.
  I didn't like the series much, at that point of time at least, but now I would really like to see it again.
- They would always catch the other teams cheating but never report them.
- The players were 100% human. And the main team wore red coloured jersey.
- Anime? Maybe. Not sure.
- It was 3D, but had a 2D feel to it.
- They played association football. In the normal association football stadia.

Comment: Were the players human? Zombies? Mascots? Anthropomorphic animals?

Comment: Hmm... if there's no advanced technology, and no fantastic elements, I don't know if this fits in the site, although perhaps if there really was the "anti gravity chamber".

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, you can be sure there was.

Comment: Galactik Football ?

Comment: This seems to have science fictional/fantastical elements now it's been identified. Whilst the whole series doesn't seem like it would be on topic to ask about, only select elements, a story id question on this should be more than okay.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is ***[Supa Strikas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supa_Strikas_(TV_series))*** (2008–2015).

> *Supa Strikas* is an animated television series about the super league's greatest football team based on the pan-African football (soccer) themed [comic of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supa_Strikas), which is produced in Malaysia by Animasia Studio, and Strika Entertainment originally in South Africa.

> In their bid to raise the Super League trophy (equivalent to UEFA Champions League), the world's greatest soccer team, Supa Strikas, must adventure through the world of soccer. Supa Strikas explore the roots of the game (from Mexico to China and other countries), meet its greatest players (past and present) and confront its most unscrupulous coaches and players! Shakes has a rival "Skarra" who him and his Coach try everything to sabotage the Strikas on their upcoming game.
>
> The story centers around the team's youngest striker, Shakes, whom many believe is the best striker in the world. But for Shakes and his teammates, being the best is only the beginning. The game's global legacy and the players who dream of being crowned Super League champs mean Shakes must constantly challenge himself to remain in contention. As a result, he often finds himself spearheading the team's exploration of the unknown – be it a strange land, a strange opposition or a new soccer challenge.
>
> Supa Strikas combines humor (often in the form of Shakes’ best mate, Spenza), action, technology and exploration in the context of a real soccer challenge. The stories are usually positive life messages that deal with self-actualization, fair play, teamwork and respect.

Comment: [This episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID36dk0Pels) appears to confirm the presence of distinctly sci-fi elements (such as robots, and a Matrix-esque "virtual reality chamber pod thing") within this series.

Answer (score 4):

Could you be thinking of *[Foot 2 Rue](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/Foot2Rue)*, aka *Street Football*?

> *Foot 2 Rue* takes place in Port-Marie, a thinly-veiled representation of Marseille. The kids of Port Marie organize a Street Football World Cup with the help of a former professional footballer, thus attracting players from all around the world and becoming famous worldwide in the process. The sport itself consists of a stripped down version of soccer, meant to be accessible to all children regardless of money and social status and in any location.

Supposedly, the Canadian team are terrible cheaters.

### Intro of *Foot 2 Rue*

It was followed by a sequel series, *[Foot 2 Rue Extreme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_2_rue_extr%C3%AAme)* which was done in 3d animation.

> Tag, ancien joueur de foot de rue, devient le demi-frère de Samy, un passionné de foot de rue extrême et capitaine de sa propre équipe, la Team, dont Tag devient le coach. La Team participe à un tournoi où différentes équipes, nommées les Ninjaz, les Deltoro, les Magics, les Darksides et la Team, s'affrontent pour décider laquelle représentera la ville à un tournoi contre les équipes de tout le pays.

Translated:

> Tag, a former street football player, becomes the half-brother of Samy, an extreme street football enthusiast and captain of his own team, the Team, of which Tag becomes the coach. The Team participates in a tournament where different teams, named Ninjaz, Deltoro, Magics, Darksides and Team, compete to decide which will represent the city in a tournament against teams from across the country.

The IMDB summary for the English version, *[Extreme Football](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6468792/)*, mentions that The Dark Sides are prone to cheating.

> Extreme Football is an urban spin off of traditional five-a-side incorporating elements of free running and acrobatics. Created by and for children, as soon as Samy discovers it he is determined to captain a team. He sets about recruiting his closest friend Greg and Mediterranean girl Ines as defenders, quick-witted Luna as the star striker and hyperactive Joey as goalkeeper. Together they form The Team. Competing in a shopping mall still under construction, rivalries are based on players' dedication to creativity, craft and skill. The Team's sworn enemies are The Dark Sides, who use dirty tactics - provocation, trickery and hoaxes. Trained by Samy's stepbrother Tag, can The Team win with style?

### Intro of *Foot 2 Rue Extreme*

Not matching, the main team wears blue uniforms in both iterations of the cartoon.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like you probably would have mentioned the zombies, but perhaps *[Mutant League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutant_League)*?

> Mutant League is an animated series based on the video games Mutant League Football and Mutant League Hockey which aired from July 2, 1994 to February 24, 1996. The show ran for two seasons, with the second typically incorporating more poignant stories and issues, while the first seemed somewhat hodgepodge with little regard for continuity (the Monsters have one win streak that ends twice, for instance).

### Intro

Comment: Not the right answer, but +1 for trying anyway. Will definitely check this out.